# GDB debug on kubernetes running container

Tags: c++, kubernetes, gdb, containers, openshift

I have a Kubernetes container running my c++ application. I now want to run that application in gdb debugger mode. So how can I start the running Kubernetes container in gdb mode?

Comment: What do you mean by gdb debugger mode? Please elaborate.

Comment: Suppose I am running my application in Linux env, then to debug I attached the gdb using gdb -p <pid> and will add the breakpoint and run it, so on BP hit, I will able to debug line by line my code.
Same thing I want to do when my application is running in the k8s container.

Comment: You can use CLI to login to the pod containing your container, open up a shell and run the same sets of commands.